# AVG function is not working perfectly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 database, one in Mysql and a second in SQL Server. In these 2 databases, I have a table `tb_Episode`, both databases have same records.

When I run this query in Mysql, it returns a result of `5.1582`, whereas in SQL Server, it returns `5`.

Why am I getting different results? I use this query - can anyone please help me, how can I resolve this error?

```
SELECT  
    AVG(CASE 
           WHEN (SN_Ep = '1' AND MonthEnd = '2017-04') 
              THEN SN_Visits 
              ELSE NULL 
        END) AS SNVisitsSNEps_2017_04 
FROM 
    tb_Episode 
WHERE 
    CustID = '27' 
    AND PayerType = 'Ep' 
    AND BranchID IN (238, 239, 240, 241)
```

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that `SN_Visits` in an integer? Aggregate functions in SQL Server return a number with the same accuracy as what was provided. If that's an interger, your average will also be an integer. Try changing `SN_Visits` to `CONVERT(decimal(10,4),SN_Visits)`.

Comment: Or do `AVG(1.0 * ...)`.

Comment: thanks to all its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server the return data-type of `AVG()` is determined by the input data-type.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql

If you average a column of integers, the result will be an integer.  If you want the result to be a different data-type, cast the input to be that data-type.

As an example...

```
AVG(
  CAST(
    CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then SN_Visits ELSE NULL END)
    AS
    DECIMAL(18,10)
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try like this -

```
AVG(

    CASE when (SN_Ep = '1' and MonthEnd='2017-04') then SN_Visits * 1. ELSE NULL END)

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some guidance for both databases:

- `else NULL` is redundant.
- If a value is a number, don't compare it to a string.

Then, you want to convert the integer type to a number for SQL Server.  A simple way is to multiply by `1.0`.

I would suggest for both:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE when SN_Ep = 1 and MonthEnd = '2017-04' THEN SN_Visits * 1.0 END) as SNVisitsSNEps_2017_04 
FROM tb_Episode 
WHERE CustID = 27 AND
      PayerType = 'Ep' AND
      BranchID IN (238, 239, 240, 241) ;
```